# Cursor jumps to left corner (windows 10 vm - kvm)

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, kvm

So I have a Windows 10 VM running on Arch Linux and it is working fine with 1 Display. When I add the second `video` tag with `virsh edit VM-name`, and get the two displays, the mouse starts moving around weird and when not in movement place it self all the way to the left. Then when I try to click anywhere it moves to the top left corner and not pressing where it was.

How can I get the mouse to move normally or debug this error?

I see the VM with virt-viewer, setup up with libvirt and has spice set to graphics.

XML:

```
<domain type="kvm" id="2">
  <name>windows10</name>
  <uuid>1814f800-8c7f-441b-9c35-bd4fdd4bb5b3</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo>
      <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/10"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit="KiB">7864320</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">7864320</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement="static">2</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-3.1">hvm</type>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state="on"/>
      <vapic state="on"/>
      <spinlocks state="on" retries="8191"/>
    </hyperv>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none"/>
    <clock offset="localtime">
      <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
      <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
      <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
      <timer name="hypervclock" present="yes"/>
    </clock>
    <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
    <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
    <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
    <pm>
      <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
      <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
    </pm>
    <devices>
      <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
      <disk type="file" device="disk">
        <driver name="qemu" type="raw" cache="none" io="native"/>
        <source file="/var/lib/libvirt/images/win10.raw"/>
        <backingStore/>
        <target dev="sda" bus="virtio"/>
        <alias name="virtio-disk0"/>
        <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x05" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
      </disk>
      <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
        <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/> 
        <source file="/usr/share/virtio-win.iso"/>
        <backingStore/>
        <target dev="sdb" bus="sata"/>
        <readonly/>
        <alias name="sata0-0-1"/>
        <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="1"/>
      </disk>
      <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
        <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
        <source file="/usr/share/win10.iso"/>
        <backingStore/>
        <target dev="sdc" bus="sata"/>
        <readonly/>
        <alias name="sata0-0-2"/>
        <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="2"/>
      </disk>
      <controller type="usb" index="0" model="qemu-xhci" ports="15">
        <alias name="usb"/>
        <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
      </controller>
      <controller type="sata" index="0">
        <alias name="ide"/>
        <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1f" function="0x2"/>
      </controller>
      <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pcie-root">
        <alias name="pcie.0"/>
      </controller>
      <controller type="pci" index="1" model="pcie-root-port">
        <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
        <target chassis="1" port="0x10"/>
        <alias name="pci.1"/>
        <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
      </controller>
      <controller type="pci" index="2" model="pcie-root-port">
        <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
        <target chassis="2" port="0x11"/>
        <alias name="pci.2"/>
        <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x1"/>
      </controller>
      <controller type="pci" index="3" model="pcie-root-port">
        <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
        <target chassis="3" port="0x12"/>
        <alias name="pci.3"/>
        <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x2"/>
      </controller>
      <controller type="pci" index="4" model="pcie-root-port">
        <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
        <target chassis="4" port="0x13"/>
        <alias name="pci.4"/>
        <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x3"/>
      </controller>
      <controller type="pci" index="5" model="pcie-root-port">
        <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
        <target chassis="5" port="0x14"/>
        <alias name="pci.5"/>
        <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x4"/>
      </controller>
      <interface type="network">
        <mac address="xxx"/>
        <source network="default" bridge="virbr0"/>
        <target dev="vnet0"/>
        <model type="e1000e"/>
        <alias name="net0"/>
        <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
      </interface>
      <serial type="pty">
        <source path="/dev/pts/2"/>
        <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
          <model name="isa-serial"/>
        </target>
        <alias name="serial0"/>
      </serial>
      <console type="pty" tty="/dev/pts/2"> 
        <source path="/dev/pts/2"/>
        <target type="serial" port="0"/>
        <alias name="serial0"/>
      </console>
      <input type="tablet" bus="usb">
        <alias name="input0"/>
        <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
      </input>
      <input type="mouse" bus="ps2">
        <alias name="input1"/>
      </input>
      <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2">
        <alias name="input2"/>
      </input>
      <graphics type="spice" port="5900" autoport="yes" listen="127.0.0.1">
        <listen type="address" address="127.0.0.1"/>
      </graphics>
      <video>
        <model type="qxl" ram="131072" vram="65536" vgamem="65536" heads="2" primary="yes"/>
        <alias name="video0"/>
        <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
      </video>
      <memballoon model="virtio">
        <alias name="balloon0"/>
        <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
      </memballoon>
    </devices>
    <seclabel type="dynamic" model="dac" relabel="yes">
      <label>+65534:+992</label>
      <imagelabel>+65534:+992</imagelabel>
    </seclabel>
  </domain>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone experiences this, the answer to my problem was to add a channel device with spicevmc. Also, make sure you have the spice-vdagent running